# Mouse property not visible in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, properties, mouse

I am currently using Visual studio 2010 ultimate edition, for creating a desktop applications using C#/. I want to display data in my data grid view into a text box, when content on a particular column / row is clicked ( double).
My problem is I don't see and options for Mouse in the properties window. Any pointers / guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: i suppose you can define a DataGridTemplateColumn instead of using the predefined columns like DataGridCheckBoxColumn, DataGridComboBoxColumn and then add an event handler to the UI element defined in the data template.

Answer (score 0):

you define a DataGridTemplateColumn and then add an event handler as shown below ( its just an example) - you can try something like that..

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown"/>
     </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And then call event for the Mouse down.

```
private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   TextBlock block = sender as TextBlock;
    //your code    
}
```